# In C#, how do i create an object within a method and add it to a list of other objects?

Tags: c#, list, class, methods, initialization

I have a program in which i would like to call an "Add" method from the main scope, which sends a new empty object to a Class method.

Within the method i assign the values i pass to the object, assign the values to the 'new' object and add the initialised object to a list.
The created list is outside of the method but still within the same class the method is in.

Is there a way to do this? I have a code snippet which might help you understand what i'm talking about..

Thank you!

```
public Kayttajat addToList(Kayttajat objects)
{

    //Adds the name
    Console.WriteLine("Käyttäjän nimi: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    //Adds a decimal amount of money
    Console.WriteLine("Käyttäjän rahasumma: ");
    decimal input2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    //Adds a PIN code
    Console.WriteLine("Käyttäjän pin: ");
    int input3 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine();

    //Adds to the list outside of the scope
    KayttajaLista.Add(objects(input, input2, input3));
    

}
```

and then i call this method from the main scope..

Class.AddToList(new objects());

Comment: Thank you, Tim!
How would you go about making a static factory method to add properties to new class instances? Can i have that method within the class or outside of it?

Comment: Lets see if i follow this correctly.. You have some class that contains a list of users (Kayttajat) and a method that is supposed to add a new user to that list?

Comment: Yeah correct! So from the main scope i use a method in another class. Within that void method, users give the instance initialisation parameters through a series of console inputs and lastly the user gets created into a list of objects / users.

If you know a better way, i'd love to hear more! Im still quite a beginner with OOP.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tenets of OOP is data encapsulation. Somewhat simplified, this means that an object owns its data, and only that object should modify it.

This means that ideally, you want the function that modifies the list in the same object that contains it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

record User {
    public string Name { get; init; } = default!;
    // Add more info fields here
}

class Users {
    private readonly List<User> UserList = new List<User>(); 
    
    public void AddNew() {

        Console.WriteLine("Käyttäjän nimi: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Add more things

        UserList.Add(new User() {
            Name = name,
            // More stuff ...
        });
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var users = new Users();
        // Add five users
        for (var i = 0;i < 5; i++ ) {
            users.AddNew();
        }
    }
}
```

But in the event that you cant do it in this way a list is passed by reference, so it can be manipulated right there in the function.

Here's a complete program to show this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

record User {
    public string Name { get; init; } = default!;
    // Add more info fields here
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public void AddNew(List<User> users) {

        Console.WriteLine("Käyttäjän nimi: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        
        // Add more things

        users.Add(new User() {
            Name = name,
            // More stuff ...
        });
    }   
    
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        
        var other = new SomeOtherClass();
        
        List<User> userList = new List<User>(); 
        
        // Add five users
        for (var i = 0;i < 5; i++ ) {
            other.AddNew(userList);
        }
        
    }
}
```